# Motion Blur keeps causing weird artifacts and making items dissapear

Tags: eevee-render-engine, artifacts, motion-blur

Enabling motion blur causes weird artifacts and making some planes disappear for a single frame.

Video Render without motion blur : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKZFl.jpg |
Video Render with motion blur enabled : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI5pk.jpg (I have to show how it looks rendered as a video, since that's literally what im trying to render it as, not a still frame)

Is there any possible way to properly set up motion blur so it doesn't mess up with the render?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1):

Caught same issue. I assume glitch is caused by combination of subdivision modifier and auto smooth normals toggled on. Found a workaround solution, disabling auto smooth fixes the issue. There is a discussion about this bug https://developer.blender.org/T80428